# Unable to query Oracle database via C# API

Tags: c#, oracle

Good morning.

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle database I have set up. before I go into detail, here's the code:

```
//string was slightly altered.
string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=name)));User Id = system; Password = mypass; ";    
string toReturn = "D.BUG-";    
using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))    
{    
    oracleConnection.Open();    
    using (OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand())    
    {    
        oracleCommand.Connection = oracleConnection;    
        oracleCommand.CommandText = "SELECT lixo FROM lixeira WHERE lixo IS NOT NULL";    
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;    
        using (OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader())    
        {     
            //This point IS reached!
            while (oracleDataReader.Read())    
                //This point is never reached...
                toReturn += oracleDataReader.GetString(0);    
        }    
    }    
}    
return toReturn;
```

Now, I know for a fact that connecting works, and I know for a fact that the table "lixeira" can be found; I have tested this by changing that name to another name, and getting the corresponding "i can't find that table" exception.

```
'ORA-00942: tabela ou visualização não existe'. (Table or View does not exist)
```

The issue is that this code is unable to read. The same query ran through SQL Developer works:
[SQL Developer screenshot of the same query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRkh3.jpg)

So, I'm kinda at a loss as to why oracleDataReader.Read() just never works. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The table exists but it doesn't exist... strange, have you checked that the user you log in from c# (in you connection string) has the needed permissions?

Comment: ....Yup. That's it. You can post this as answer, I'll accept it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your wellcome, we're here to help each other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your user/password in the connection string is the correct one.

If a table doesn't exist but exists... it probably doesn't exist for your current user (= that user has not the necessary permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct, I am just adding another bit. 
can you replace your query as following :

```
SELECT lixo FROM <table owner>.lixeira WHERE lixo IS NOT NULL
```

This will give more appropriate error of what you are missing. 
Its probably a permission (grant select) issue.

- Abhi

Comment: I have personally confirmed this. Thank you. As I created a new user and went ahead to test it, the error was much, much clearer.

 'ORA-01045: user C##CLOUD lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied'.

Comment: And, upon correcting that, but revoking SELECT permission from C##CLOUD, the error reported was: 

'ORA-01031: privilégios insuficientes'. (Insufficient privileges). 

Which is a far more debug-friendly error.